# How to totally clear Windows7 DNS cache?

Tags: windows, dns

The command ipconfig /flushdns does not clear all entries.
Check using ipconfig /displaydns on your side.
Here I still have some entries I can’t clear.

Does someone know how to erase all?
Thanks.

Comment: What entries? I don't have that issue when running ipconfig/flushdns. If you have entries in your hosts file those entries will be reloaded when you flush the DNS cache.

Comment: Can you confiirm you are not seeing HOSTS file entries as suggested by @joeqwerty

Comment: Also, if any software is actively using the internet the entries may be repopulated pretty much instantly after they are deleted.  You could try putting everything on one line to minimize the delay: `ipconfig /flushdns & ipconfig /displaydns`

Answer (score 9):

Use the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
net stop dnscache 


net stop dnscache
The DNS Client service is stopping.
The DNS Client service was stopped successfully.


ipconfig /displaydns

Windows IP Configuration

Could not display the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

Comment: Don't forget to start the dnscache service again by issuing `net start dnscache`

Comment: Already done and it doesn’t clear the entries.

Comment: @Sven: I provided a demo.

Comment: Where is it Greg?

Comment: If the service has been stopped the command ipconfig /displaydns won’t be able to start. And if you restart it you will see again the entries.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the cache is cleared if it isn't running.

Comment: Nope, sorry. -- "The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service."

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS cache is also automatically populated with whatever is hardcoded into your local hosts file. An ipconfig/flushdns will not remove those entries. In order to verify that your hosts file doesn't have some of these static host name to IP addresses navigate to your &windir&\System32\Drivers\etc\ folder and open the *hosts* file in Notepad or Wordpad. Ensure that there are no entries or that you comment the entries out with a "#" sign at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

ipconfig/flushdns then hit enter.

Do this 3 or 4 times in a row (use the F3 key at the command prompt and it will populate the last entry).

Then type in ipconfig/displaydns and you should see the message that there is nothing to display. Ensure that all your browsers are CLOSED before doing this,as it will keep populating the latest entry.

Answer (score 0):

Just try these:

1: Internet modem / router switch off and on. Wait 2-3 minutes.

2: use this command in cmd:

`nslookup yourdomain.com`

( yourdomain.com means what domain you like to see )

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Your answer does not explain how to clear the DNS-cache on Windows 7. Aside from that, not all DNS server give out new leases after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my post where advised a new solution :)